# My image slider has white spaces

Tags: javascript, css, image, slider

Plz see the following link,
http://www.beta.storeji.in/
when the image slides the next image wont slide appear until the sliding is done and white space is showed instead of image. How to fix this?

this is my slider javascript code

```
function slide()
{
    if($('.current').is(':last-child')){
        $('.current').removeClass('current');
        $('#imgholder img:first-child').addClass('current');
        $('#imgholder').animate({left: '0px'});
    }
    else{
        $('.current').removeClass(function(){
            $(this).next().addClass('current');
            return 'current';
        });
        $('#imgholder').animate({left: '-=980'},{duration: 'slow', easing: 'easeOutBounce' });
        }
}
var loop_handle= setInterval("slide()",'5000');
```

Comment: try making the left: '-=980" left:'=-980"

Comment: @albert, I'm not against somebody learning something new, but maybe the OP just does not realize this wheel has already been invented.

Comment: I found it easier to create my own rather than using a lib for my module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error on your picslider.css sheet, the width and height are not properly set;

```
#imgholder{
    position: absolute;
    width: 5880;
    height: 490;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Fix that and it should work fine.

**Fixed.**

```
#imgholder{
    position: absolute;
    width: 5880px;
    height: 490px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```